# DateDiff in VB...Finding 6 month intervals

Tags: vb.net, datediff

My code is:

```
    Try
        For Each fi As IO.FileInfo In New IO.DirectoryInfo(BACKUP).GetFiles()
            If DateDiff(DateInterval.Month, fi.LastWriteTime, Now) > 6 Then
                fi.Delete()
            End If
        Next
```

I am just wondering why it won't delete a file from 02/04/2014.  It is over 6 months ago but the file is still around.  Any tips as to why this is?

Comment: Did this throw any errors?

Comment: No errors, it just won't delete the files that I need to be deleted after that 6 month mark

Comment: It might be returning -6, try switching date1 and date2. Or use `abs(datediff ...`.

Comment: I tried switching the dates and it still didn't delete the file

Comment: Have you checked what `fi.LastWriteTime` is returning?  You say the file is **from** 02/04/2014 (I assume 4th Feb 2014 after reading other comments!), but is that the creation date, modified date or last accessed date?

Comment: fi.LastWriteTime is returning 02/04/2014, todays date is being returned as 08/06/2014

Comment: As @Joiner pointed out below, your function will only delete the file if the difference is 7 months. DateDiff returns a long, there are no fractions of months. Make it >=6 and it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both answers provide the cause, but neither provides a solution. Change this:

```
If DateDiff(DateInterval.Month, fi.LastWriteTime, Now) > 6 Then
```

To this:

```
If DateDiff(DateInterval.Month, fi.LastWriteTime, Now) >= 6 Then
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim Date1 As New Date(2014, 2, 4) ' fi.LastWriteTime
Dim Date2 As Date = Now ' 08/06/2014
Dim Diff As Long = DateDiff(DateInterval.Month, Date1, Date2)
```

`Diff` equals *6*. `> 6` equals ***at least*** 7.
***6* is not higher than *6***.

Comment: @TheBlueDog 02 >> month and 04 >> day?

Comment: Yes I am using US date, today is 08/06/2014 so it should be 6 months 2 days which I thought would delete the file from the records

Answer (score 0):

From the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/b5xbyt6f(v=vs.90).aspx);

> **Larger Intervals.** If Interval is set to DateInterval.Year, the return value is calculated purely from the year parts of Date1 and Date2. Similarly, the return value for **DateInterval.Month** is calculated purely from the year and month parts of the arguments, and for DateInterval.Quarter from the quarters containing the two dates.

So in this case, the result will be `6` - i.e. 08 minus 02 - which fails the test.

Comment: So that's saying that even though it is older than 6 months, because months is not over 6 it won't be deleted?

Comment: @user3630473: Older than 6 months means at least 6 months old. "At least" is written as >= in any programming language.

Comment: Exactly, as @Neolisk points out, the solution is to change your maths.  It's ignoring the number of days.  I **think** you can use the System.Math namespace and Timespan object to get the number of months in decimals... but I could be wrong...

Comment: @Grim: TimeSpan does not have TotalMonths, because months are subjective and not consistent.

Comment: @Neolisk - yes, I remember now.  I must be getting too old for this; I can't look stuff up or remember it before you lot have all replied :P

Comment: I think last time I did something similar, I used the total number of days and compared to (30 days x 6 months = 180 days) and basically just deleted stuff if it was over 180 days old instead.  Or of course, you can roll a whole new routine to return the number of months and days... etc...

Comment: I didn't realize that it did not take days into consideration.  I have since made the adjustment to use 182 days (about half the year).  Thanks again for your help